# Using Wild Shape to hide (as a parasite)

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, optional-rules

A question came up in a game recently. Can a Druid use Wild Shape to transform into a parasitic animal and thus occupy the same square as the host, as well as smuggle the Druid into some other place?

How would you run it if a Druid Wild Shaped into a tapeworm? Could she use that to sneak past some guards inside another person? The general rule is that if they are inside another animal and de-wild shape, they just appear next to the first creature rather than making it explode by resizing inside it, so I am not so much concerned with how the end game would work out, but whether or not it would be allowed, how combat might work, stuff like that. Thoughts?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115618/discussion-on-question-by-colinpartlan-using-wild-shape-to-hide-as-a-parasite).

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Comment: For these types of questions, it's better to stick to the current beasts described in the Monster Manual and avoid strange transformations. Our lives as DMs will be better.

Answer (score 12):

#### Homebrew problems require homebrew solutions.

To my knowledge, there is no tapeworm statblock. Since it is entirely up to the DM to create one, its entirely up to them what its form is capable of.

To this end, chapter 9 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* has some guidance. It is quite long and detailed, but I can quote the [introduction to this section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#CreatingaMonster) which encourages creating new monsters for your game:

> The Monster Manual contains hundreds of ready-to-play monsters, but it doesn’t include every monster that you can imagine. Part of the D&D experience is the simple joy of creating new monsters and customizing existing ones, if for no other reason than to surprise and delight your players with something they’ve never faced before.

Comment: *It is quite long and detailed* so is a tapeworm,  though they may be said to have tails ...